# rails 5.1 API and Jbuilder render problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After setup a simple API and try to login with a simple session controller

**Session Controller**

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: [:email])
  if user && user.authenticate([:password])
    render json: {token:  user.access_token}, status: 200
  else
    render text: "Email and password combination are invalid", status: 422
  end
end
```

in the logs show

> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template sessions/create,
>   application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json],
>   :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby,
>   :jbuilder]}. Searched in:   * "/home/daniel/ranks/app/views" ):

after googling around seems a issue with jbuilder and the workaround that some proposed was to: in the application controller

```
include ActionView::Rendering

def render_to_body(options)
  _render_to_body_with_renderer(options) || super
end
```

but the problem persist so someone has any idea how to solve this issue with `rails 5.1` and `jbuilder 2.7.0`?

Comment: You should not handle errors with `render text` while creating API instead, you should use `render json: {errors: "Email and password combination are invalid"}, status: 422 `

Comment: First of all please check any tutorial how to create rails api https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one

Comment: not related not with your answer but try using safe navigation operator `user&.authenticate`